# Angular2 Assign variable

Tags: angular, variables, typescript, assign

```
<div *ngIf="!(lookupModel && lookupModel[displayProperty]) && ((_items | filter:search:displayProperty).length == 1)">
   <div *ngFor="let item of _items | filter:search:displayProperty; this.lookupModelChange=item;" >
         {{item[displayProperty]}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Hello guys. You can see my *ngFor in div block element. Actually this for has only one iteration ( because i don't know how can I do this differently - if you know you can also help me ^^ ). But, main proble is How can i assign variable from code, which is lookupModalChange to variable from *ngFor - item. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Actually, I have changed something ( this of course doesn't work aswell )

```
<div *ngIf="!(lookupModel && lookupModel[displayProperty]) && ((_items | filter:search:displayProperty).length === 1)">
   <div [lookupModelChange]="(_items | filter:search:displayProperty)">
      {{lookupModelChange[displayProperty]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Getting this error:

Can't bind to 'lookupModelChange' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Do you want to assign the **chosen or mouse move over** item to the variable (lookupModalChange)? Because there are multiple items in the array, which item you want to assign?

Comment: No no no. It's just one element in this array ( trust me, there is *ngIf with length === 1 ). I don't know how to avoid this *ngFor :/

Comment: so you mean you only want to assign one element in the array assign to the other variable?  such as list[0] to lookupModalChange?

Comment: You can get rid of `this` keyword in template.

Comment: @XinMeng yes, that's what i want to.

Comment: @micronyks yes i delete it. Nothing... doesn't work :(

Comment: I will update, what i have done from last 10 minutes